# Expansion of an ideal gas in an evacuated bottle having nonconducting walls

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

In the free expansion of ideal gas in a vacuum $dW = 0$ as $p_{ext} = 0$ and $dU = 0$ therefore there is no change in temperature of the ideal gas also. what i want to know that can the following situation also classify as a free expansion of a ideal gas and if no why ? the situation is as follows-

" An evacuated bottle with nonconducting walls is connected through a valve to a large supply of gas, where the pressure is $P_0$ and the temperature is $T_0$. The valve is open slightly, and helium flows into the bottle until the pressure inside the bottle is $P_0$. "

is the process also quasi static. As the bottle is a vacuum it seems that the process is free expansion but i dont think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question whether or not it is a free expansion relates to what you choose as your thermodynamic system. Here are two choices, both applicable to the situation you describe.

1. We suppose the 'large supply of gas' is itself large but finite, and we suppose it is contained in a large vessel with rigid walls. Let the thermodymamic system under study be this gas. No heat enters or leaves, and since the walls are rigid no work is done on the system, so this system undergoes a process of free expansion as the gas expands into the bottle.
2. Alternatively, take as your thermodynamic system just that part of the gas which ends up in the bottle. You could imagine a thin flexible bag around it if you like. Now the process is not a free expansion, because the rest of the gas does work on your system as it pushes against the bag and this bag (or boundary) moves.

Comment: I understand choice 1 as it’s the same as the typical example of a single rigid insulated vessel with a partition with ideal gas in one half and other half evacuated. I don’t quite understand what/ where the thin flexible bag is

Comment: @BobD in the 2nd choice, the gas that ends up in the bottle is a closed system, and work is done on this gas by the gas behind it (within the large reservoir) in pushing this gas into the inlet of the valve.  No other work is done on this gas.  So the work done on it is $P_0v_0n$, where $v_0$ is the specific volume of the gas in the reservoir and n is the number of moles of gas that enter the bottle.  The problem can also be analyzed using the open-system (control volume) version of the first law, where just the bottle is the control volume.  Both approaches give the same answer.

Comment: @ChetMiller But if the large vessel and the evacuated vessel together comprise the system, then it is isolated and we have a free expansion, do we not? The no drop in pressure is problematic since it implies an infinitely large initial volume of helium. There must be some pressure drop, no matter how small. Correct? What I didn't understand about choice 2 was the reference to the thin flexible bag.

Comment: @ChetMiller Upon re-reading Andrew's answer I see that in choice 2 he is looking only at the gas that winds up in the bottle as constituting the system- so now I understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

As @Andrew Steene pointed out, it depends on how you define the "system". If you define the system as the combination of the two rigid insulated vessels and their contents (Andrew's choice 1) then the system is isolated (can exchange no mass or energy with its surroundings).Then you have a free expansion.

> is the process also quasi static?

I would add a free expansion is not considered quasi-static. Even though the helium may slowly move into the evacuated chamber, it nonetheless expands across a finite pressure difference until it approaches equilibrium. That makes the process irreversible. You know it is irreversible because you would not expect the helium to spontaneously return to its original.  Work would be required.

**UPDATE**:

This update is given in light of the following additional comments you have given.

> if i take both the container as my system then the process is a free
>   expansion right. If the gas expanding from the container has
>   temperature 0 then after expanding into the evacuated bottle the
>   temperature should remain the same ($_0$) but in my textbook it is
>   written that the temperature of the gas will change to $\frac{C_p}{C_v}T_0$.
>   Where is that i am wrong?

For a free expansion of an ideal gas (aka Joule expansion) there is no change in internal energy. Also, for an ideal gas, its internal energy is only a function of the temperature of the gas according to

$$\Delta U=c_{v}\Delta T$$

Consequently *if the book says there is a temperature change, we do not, by definition have a free expansion of an ideal gas.* (It should be noted that real gases can experience a temperature change)

> what if the gas coming from the container is infinitely large as
>   compared to the bottle wont the pressure be constant in that
>   situation?

Such an assumption would be inconsistent with the temperature change given in the book, and here's why:

Given the specific heats of helium, the book says the final temperature of the helium is about 1.67 times the original temperature, or a 67% increase in temperature. For an ideal gas that means the increase in volume of the helium gas is also increase 67% because the idea gas law gives us

$$\frac{P_{i}V_{i}}{T_{i}}=\frac{P_{f}V_{f}}{T_{f}}$$.

If the initial and final pressures are the same, the initial and final ratios of volume to temperature are also the same. Finally, that means the volume of the bottle, into which helium expanded, is 67% of the initial infinite volume of the helium! The container can’t be infinitely larger compared to the bottle.

The above being said, I must admit I do not know what kind of process can produce the final temperature given in the book. I will reach out to a trusted colleague of mine to see if he knows.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Andrew stean if i take both the container as my system then the process is a free expansion right. If the gas expanding from the container has temperature $T_0$ then after expanding into the evacuated bottle the temperature should remain the same ($T_0$)  but in my textbook it is written that the temperature of the gas will change to $\frac{C_p} {C_v} T_0 $. Where is that i am wrong?

Comment: @tanuj23199 The problem is the pressure can’t be constant and the volume increase without a temperature change. There’s a problem with the question itself.

Comment: what if the gas coming from the container is infinitely large as compared to the bottle wont the pressure  be constant in that situation

Comment: @tanuj23199 In light of the new information you have given concerning the final temperature of the helium, I am going to update my answer. Stand by.

Comment: @tanuj23199 Please clarify. Did the book say $\frac{C_p}{C_v}T_0$ is the change in temperature ($\Delta T$) or the final temperature ($T_f$)?.

Comment: $\frac{C_p} {C_v} T_0  $ is the final temperature

Comment: @Chet Miller. Hi Chet. See the above post. Can you think of any ideal gas process where the final temperature is $\frac{C_p}{C_v}T_0$ where $T_0$ is the initial temperature?

Comment: I think I can.  I think it is the final temperature in the process described in the original post.

Comment: @Chet Miller and exactly what is the math for that process?

Comment: I am away from my computer now.  I will add an Answer that addresses this question later.

Comment: @Chet Miller Thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 1):

This is in response to @BobD 's inquiry as to how to obtain the final temperature using the first law of thermodynamics.  There are two equivalent ways of doing this, using either (1) the usual closed system version of the first law, or (2) the open system (control volume) version of the first law.  Both methods give exactly the same results.

1. Closed system version

The system here is chosen as all the gas that will eventually end up in the bottle.  There is work done on this gas as it is pushed into the valveby the gas immediately behind it in the gas supply.  This work is given by $P_0v_0n$, where $v_0$ is the specific volume in the gas supply and n is the number of moles of gas that enter the tank.  So, from the closed system version of the first law, we have:$$\Delta U=n(u_f-u_0)=nC_v(T_f-T_0)=nP_0v_0$$where $u_0$ is the molar specific internal energy of the gas in the supply.  Now, from the ideal gas law, $$P_0v_0=RT_0$$Therefore we have $$C_v(T_f-T_0)=RT_0$$From this, it follows that $$T_f=\frac{C_p}{C_v}T_0$$

2. Open system version

In applying the open system version of the first law, we take as our control volume the combination of the valve and the bottle.  For this system, there is no shaft work done, and the open system version of the first law is expressed as $$U_f=nu_f=nh_0$$where $h_0$ is the enthalpy per mole in the supply (and thus equal to the enthalpy per mole of the inlet stream to the control volume), with $$h_0=u_0+P_0v_0$$and$$u_f=u_0+C_v(T_f-T_0)$$ Combining these equations, we obtain $$u_f=u_0+C_v(T-T_0)=u_0+P_0v_0$$or again:$$C_v(T_f-T_0)=RT_0$$

Comment: Thanks Chet. What I didn’t consider using the closed system approach is the work done by the gas in the large vessel as work done by the surroundings on the gas being pushed into the bottle, the system, if I’m thinking about it correctly. Can you add to your answer whether or not this process constitutes a free (Joule) expansion of an ideal gas in the closed or open system version.

Comment: @BobD It's not a "free expansion" as long as it is getting throttled through the valve and then getting partially recompressed in the bottle.